# Which act of Congress authorized the Ukrainian aid which was allegedly withheld?

Tags: united-states, law, congress, ukraine, foreign-aid

According to multiple media sources, U.S. aid to Ukraine was authorized by Congress.  I am having difficulty identifying precisely which act would have authorized the specific aid which the Trump administration is accused of withholding in 2019.  It would be interesting to read what the act actually says, and how members of Congress voted on it.

- There was a [2014 act](https://www.rferl.org/a/ukraine-united-states-house-of-representatives-aid-/25317731.html) for aid to Ukraine.  However, it is not clear to me if this act is still in effect 5 years later.
- The Department of Defense Appropriations Act 2020 allocates [$700 million for Ukraine](https://www.unian.info/politics/10592613-u-s-house-of-representatives-approves-700-mln-aid-package-for-ukraine-embassy.html), but it is [currently in House committee](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/116/hr2968) and is not yet law.

**Which act of the U.S. Congress** (e.g. by resolution number, official title, or public law number) **authorized the 2019 aid to Ukraine, which was allegedly withheld?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to [justsecurity.org](https://www.justsecurity.org/66425/ukrainian-funding-delay-created-a-paper-trail-that-congress-should-follow/) which provides a timeline which starts with:

> [September 28, 2018](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/6157?r=1) – Congress enacts a Department of Defense spending bill that includes $250 million in Ukrainian military assistance funding. Later appropriations bills provided additional funding for Ukraine.

That date links to [H.R.6157 - Department of Defense and Labor, Health and Human Services, and Education Appropriations Act, 2019 and Continuing Appropriations Act, 2019](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/6157?r=1).

The linked summary includes the following on Ukraine:

> (Sec. 9013) Provides additional funding for the Ukraine Security Assistance Initiative for: (1) assistance, including training; equipment; lethal assistance; logistics support, supplies and services; sustainment; and intelligence support to the military and national security forces of Ukraine, and (2) replacement of any weapons or articles provided to Ukraine from the U.S. inventory.
>
> Permits DOD to accept equipment procured using funds provided under this section or prior Acts that was transferred to the security forces of Ukraine and returned to the United States.
>
> (Sec. 9014) Permits funds provided by this title to be used for the replacement of funds for items provided to the government of Ukraine from the U.S. inventory, to the extent that it is permitted by section 9013 of the division.
>
> (Sec. 9015) Prohibits funds provided by this division under section 9013 for Assistance and Sustainment to the Military and National Security Forces of Ukraine from being used to procure or transfer man-portable air defense systems.

Comment: You can also see the voting records, [senate](https://www.senate.gov/legislative/LIS/roll_call_lists/roll_call_vote_cfm.cfm?congress=115&session=2&vote=00193) and [house](http://clerk.house.gov/evs/2018/roll313.xml). Some interesting votes: Sanders Nay, Warren Yea, Paul Nay; Khanna Yea, Gabbard Yea.